# Where are the PHP 8.2 deprecation logs stored in Laravel 10.22.0?

Tags: php, laravel, newrelic

I am running into a critical issue after upgrading from php 8.0.8 to 8.2 and from laravel 8 to 10.22.0.

I also updated newrelic agemt and removed https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-monolog-logenricher-php/ as it does not work with php >= 8.1 (requires older monolog 2).

**My problem is:**
Sudden increase in newrelic logs related to php deprecation notices. I did not instrument any extra logging in my code aside the mentioned updates.

[image]

**Problem 2: I have no idea where they come from!**
I am using the php-fpm-nginx docker image `kristijorgji/php-fpm-8-nginx:0.0.6`, code at https://github.com/kristijorgji/docker-images/tree/main/php-fpm-8-nginx + some extra newrelic agent installation not present there.

**Things I investigated so far**

1. I looked into the running docker container logs, I see only the nginx outputs. (`docker-compose logs --tail=100 api`)
2. I looked inside the docker container
   and have no logs at `/var/log/php` or `/var/log/nginx/error.log`
3. I looked at `storage/logs/laravel.log` and it has randomly messages, but never the deprecation notices

**4. I debugged in detail what happens within Laravel**

First I noticed that `/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php:357` gets called by Laravel at `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Logger.php:184` `writeLog` to write the log of warning level for the deprecatino.

Moving forward the Logger.php:357 has only the Monolog NullHandler as handler `vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/NullHandler.php` so no log is output anywhere
[image]

So where and how does Newrelic finds and forward these logs then?!?!?! if they are not written anywhere?

Diving further, I noticed that after calling the nullhandler that does nothing, Laravel also fires one `MessageLogged` event at `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Logger.php:248`
[image]
In my development local env I see no listeners for `MessageLogged` but newrelic is not installed in local.

I believe that maybe Newrelic detects the framework and adds some listener "magically" here by injecting php code in runtime.
I see no other log output from my debug and can't tell where and how newrelic finds those deprecations.

Someone can inform me about this if you have more knowledge

**So the mistery is: How and where does newrelic find these deprecation logs and forwards them ?**
Or how can I see them myself during development ?

I want to stop forwarding them to newrelic as it increased by 100 times the cost and they are useless, repeat all the time.

I want to see them in the local development environment so I fix them instead.

PS: I have no idea why newrelic archived https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-monolog-logenricher-php/

Their log forwarding is broken for newer php versions, the enricher worked great also used the extra context like userId etc that we could attach.

Comment: Did you follow the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/logging#logging-deprecation-warnings?

Comment: @matiaslauriti I upgraded from laravel 8 to 10.2.2. I don't have that configuration key. My question as part of this post is, assuming these are stored somewhere, where is the location ? I cannot see those logs during development when I call the part of code that uses older php stuff

Comment: I am not sure how you follow the upgrade, but that is the Laravel 10 documentation. If you do not have `config/logging.php` or you have the mentioned keys (from that documentation) missing, just add them to the `config/logging.php` file and you will start getting the deprecation logs directly from Laravel

Comment: You can add that deprecation key to your logging.php, it doesn't have to be in there to start with, and most likely won't

Comment: I will try that, but still you are not unsolving the mystery: Where are those logs going now and how I can see them currently ? Newrelic manages to find them somewhere but I cannot

Comment: I am assuming that PHP is using `stderr` or similar, and new relic is listening to it, or something similar like that. I have no idea what PHP config you have, but you should also be able to always log deprecations directly from PHP FPM to a log file, but you have to turn that on if I am not confused. I did not do this in a very long time. Other times, new relic directly compiles their own plugin into PHP FPM, so it is directly done by them

Comment: All the configuration of my php is here https://github.com/kristijorgji/docker-images/tree/main/php-fpm-8-nginx, I am using that docker image. Supervisord starts php-fpm and nginx servers from php-fpm

Comment: I see that php-fpm in supervisor config is `stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr` outputs to stderr

Comment: According to `docker`, docker-compose logs, and docker logs should show both stdout and stderr but I don't see the deprecation noticeses there ....

Comment: For first, laravel drop support for switmailer. You dont follow upgrade guide and try to solve a problem that doesn't need to be solved

Comment: @Maksim I have more deprecation notes, I posted only that example. So your answer is not relevant because still we want to understand everything that goes on and how things work, instead of just silencing them

Comment: Things will work when you make full upgrade - and deprecation notices will be disappear.

Comment: @Maksim I did already the full upgrade, also added logger config and all as explained in the docs. If you mean by full upgrade to upgrade all other libraries not related to laravel to last versions then that is not easy. Most of them are deprecated or use older php version features that have deprecation errors. Still, my idea is how to troubleshoot this, ingore the upgrade and libraries. Let's focus on understanding where those deprecations are output and how newrelic finds them

Comment: But can you be FULLY SURE that libraries with deprecation work as expected? You just try sweep problems under the rug - and this is really bad thing, local community doesn’t take this very well

Comment: @Maksim please focus on the question. Yes I am sure due to e2e tests that we have and functional tests. If a library is archived or uses old php version it does not mean that it is not functional. If it is archived it is a red flag for the future for sure but does not mean it is broken. Issue is also with toerh code not related to the library and the configuration of the system like how do these logs flow

Comment: I updated my question with deep debugging and investigation results by debugging Laravel. I noticed that no log is output anywhere but still Newrelic finds and forwards those deprecations. My assumption is that they listen to Laravel events and might inject php code in runtime somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deprecation logs were going to monolog `vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/NullHandler.php` as I did explain in the updated questions. This handler does not output the logs anywhere.

If you want to output the deprecation logs in some particular channel, you can change `configs/logging.php`

What remains still an open question is:
Why does Newrelic listen to Laravel log events and forward logs meant to be sent nowhere (to the null handler that does nothing) ?

I think this is not a correct behavior.
I am in touch with them regarding this.